# Is there an alternate way to get receipts from the Mac App Store

Tags: mac-appstore

I purchased an app (Divvy) from the Mac App Store ten days ago and still have not received an email receipt for the purchase. The e-mail address in the App Store Account Settings is correct and it's not in the Spam folder. The same account gets receipts fine when I make purchases in the iTunes Store.

Is there a way to either:

1. View old receipts somewhere, or
2. Get receipts emailed again?

The reason I need the receipt itself is so I can turn in an expense report. In the case of Divvy, it's not that expensive, but if I can't get receipts, I'm certainly not going to make further purchases.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While going off of the recommendation from @Mark to contact Apple Support I found a way to (kind of) get a receipt by following the directions [on this page](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2727) which shows you how to get order numbers.

Basically, in iTunes, you click on your username/email-address and then log in. This will bring up your Account Information window where you can select the "See All" under the "Purchase History" section. This will take you to a list of transactions.

Unfortunately, you can't print these out directly, but you can take a screen grab of the receipt (Cmd+Shift+3 or Cmd+Shift+4) and then print the resulting graphic.

A little bit of a hack, but it gets you there.

Comment: You can try to print it via CMD+P, Print popup window is there, but I can only see the empty page.

Comment: It is ridiculous, and it is not the first time with apple :)

Answer (score 3):

**If your purchase is within the last 90 days**, you can view it online as follows:

If you go to https://reportaproblem.apple.com and you are logged in with your Apple ID, you can view recent purchases, and print out the receipts, or email them to an address.

**If your purchase is older** however, I have found a way where you can request that a receipt for a purchase be emailed to you once again, but you cannot do it in your browser, it requires either an iOS device or a Mac with iTunes:

For iOS Devices (instructions as of iOS 11.4):

1. Open Settings.app
2. Tap on your name where it says "Apple ID, iCloud, iTunes & App Store" (it's the first item in the list)
3. Tap on "iTunes & App Store" (it should show the email address of your App Store / iTunes account underneath)
4. Tap on the first item at the top that looks like this: "Apple ID: your_email@your_domain.com"
5. Choose "View Apple ID" from the list and authenticate if necessary.
6. Scroll down and tap on "Purchase History"
7. Choose your time range as necessary by tapping on "Last 90 Days".
8. Find the purchase you need the receipt for, and then tap on the row that says "Total Billed: $XX.XX" and has the rightward pointing chevron/arrow. This will take you to the Order/Receipt.
9. Scroll right to the bottom, and you will see a "Resent" button. Tap it, and a new copy of the receipt will be sent to the email address of your Apple ID.

For macOS:

1. Open iTunes
2. Sign in with your Apple ID if you aren't already (under the Account menu).
3. From the Account menu in the menu bar choose "View My Account..."
4. Under Purchase History, click on "See All".
5. Choose the desired date range at the top left.
6. Find the order that you need the receipt for and click on the number next to "ORDER ID" in the top right of the block for the order. This will expand the block to show more details of the order.
7. In the bottom left of the expanded block (underneath your billing address) you will see a small link entitled "Resend". Click it and a copy of the receipt will be resent to the email address of your Apple ID.

Note: You can only resend receipts for purchases that actually have value and were billed to a payment method.

Based on instructions found in the following Apple Support Document: https://support.apple.com/en-us/ht204088

Comment: problem is there is only some last a few

Comment: @BGBruno you are right, unfortunately the "Report a Problem" website only shows purchases for the last 90 days. I did however just find a way to track down older purchases and get a copy of the receipt emailed to you, however you need to use either iTunes on a Mac or an iOS device to do it. I've updated my answer with detailed instructions.

Comment: Thanks! reportaproblem.apple.com -> Invoices was just what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue for something I bought and needed a receipt, but Apple did not send an email which it used to do (for the apps that I did not need to claim on expenses).

To get a receipt, I contacted Apple support via their [web form](http://www.apple.com/uk/support/mac/app-store/contact.html?form=account&topic=Mac%20App%20Store%20Account%20and%20Billing). Note that that might be the UK form only.

To get there got to apple.com, choose support on the top bar; then choose "Mac App Store" and "Contact Support >> Account and Billing."

Comment: U.S. support page is found at: http://www.apple.com/support/mac/app-store/ - While looking for the order number that page requested, I found a knowledge base article that got me to the receipt. I've added an answer to this question with those details. Thanks for getting me pointed in the right direction.

Comment: Or try directly at: https://getsupport.apple.com/ServiceOptionAction.action

Answer (score 1):

These days you can view all your purchase receipts through iTunes (even if you bought the item through the App Store and not iTunes) - just go to "View my account", and then "Purchase History". Important to go through "View my account", there is also a "Purchases" menu item under "Account" but it is not the same.

Answer (score -1):

You should always be able to see your up to date purchase history from the App Store menu.

Store -> View my account...

Sign in and look over your purchase history. I'm not aware of a way to get an email summary or duplicate receipts mailed again.

Comment: Yeah, I can see that alright. (It's actually just under the "Purchases" tab/button.) The trick is that I need the receipt for an expense report. Not a huge deal for this purchase, but I'm certainly not going to continue to buy stuff that I can't get reimbursed for. (Note: I update the original question to help clarify that.)

Comment: I've never had an expense report declined when I print a screen capture or just fill out a missing expense receipt form as needed. You could ask nicely to [billing support](http://www.apple.com/support/itunes/account/) (look for Express Lane on the page) - they might be able to help.